# When is it acceptable to say a company is headquartered

Tags: verbs

Quite often, I read a company is *headquartered* somewhere. When is this acceptable? To my ear, headquartering sound distinctly wrong, but http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/headquarter lists it as

- transitive verb:  to place in headquarters
- intransitive verb:  to make one's headquarters

I'm not sure what "to make one's headquarters" means here.

Comment: ... Set up base.

Comment: Try using a [different dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/headquarter?searchDictCode=all). If you Google *"makes its headquarters"*, you will find lots of hits of the form *"X makes its headquarters in Chicago."* But that definition isn't very enlightening if you don't know that idiom.

Comment: To "make ones headquarters" means to create/place the "main office".

Comment: The building where the senior leadership team makes its offices is usually called the headquarters-  Literally: "where the head (CEO) is quartered (lodged)."

Comment: It should be noted that "is headquartered" is just slightly informal.  If you want to be fully formal you would say "CompanyXX has it's headquarters at/in SomeLocation", or something like that.

Comment: If you want to be formal you wouldn't say "it's headquarters." You would say "its headquarters" because "it's" means "it is" (it's a contraction - see?) and "its" is the possessive form of the pronoun "it." :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To headquarter](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/headquarters):( intr.)

> - to establish one's headquarters.

Looking at [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=company%20is%20headquartered&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccompany%20is%20headquartered%3B%2Cc0) the expression *the company is headquartered* has been more and more common since the 60's. 
It refers to the fact that the company in question has  established its headquarters in that place.

- Dawn Exports was established in 2000. The company is headquartered in Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu. The company manufactures and supplies horticultural products and bio- diesel. (2008)
- Companies are also encouraged to promptly distribute their releases to Associated Press and United Press International as well as to newspapers in New York City and in cities where the company is headquartered or has plants or other ...(2007)
- The company is headquartered in Toronto. John Cruickshank, former vice-president and creative director at Case Associates in Toronto...(1978)